# I have connected MySql database with SQL Developer but i am unable to update tables or stored procedure

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have connected MySql database with SQL Developer but, I am unable to update/edit tables from UI and stored procedure also.

Here you can see edit or other option are not present here:

[image: here you can see edit or other option are not present here]

Comment: SQL Developer is for Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: The similar tool for MySQL is MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You can able do update record using update query, right??

Comment: @Barmar I know about sql workbench, but I am used to of  SQL Developer.

Comment: @SagarGangwal, Yes I can update through query. But this not I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize SQL Developer works with multiple databases.

Answer (score 2):

For full Graphical User Interface support, you need to be connected to an Oracle Database.

MySQL connectivity is reserved for migrating those MySQL databases to Oracle.

You can browse and query your MySQL instance. If you want to do an insert, update, delete, you need to run that via SQL in a SQL Worksheet.

Comment: Ah that's the reason. Thanks @thatjeffsmith  for your answer